# How to match values using one regular expression instead of two?

Tags: php, regex

I want to catch values from this string:

```
$data='1=A
5=B
7=F
11=G';
```

The next piece of code works fine, but is using two regular expressions. Is there a way to use only one?

```
$i = 1;

if (!preg_match("/\n$i=(.*)/",$data,$m))
{
  preg_match("/^$i=(.*)/",$data,$m);
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to just return `A`?

Comment: Sure. And G for $i=11. But question is can it be solved with only one expression?

Comment: how about using /[\d]+=(.*)/g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think multiline mode is what you're looking for:

```
preg_match("/^$i=(.*)/m",$data,$m);
```

The `m` modifier allows the start anchor (`^`) to match the beginning of any *line* instead of just the beginning of the string.  It still prevents a match on (`11=G`) because the `1` has to be at the beginning of the line and immediately by `=`.  Is that what you meant?